# Why should one avoid doing CPU-intensive task using an event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a tutorial I've read that one should you Node's event-loop approach mainly for I/O intensive tasks. Like reading from hard disk or using network. But **not** for CPU-intensive task.

**What's the concrete reason for the quoted statements?**

Or the otherwayaround asked:

**What would happen if you occupy Node.js with CPU-intesive tasks to do?**

Comment: It would block the event loop and your application would become non-responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node uses a small number of threads to handle many clients. In Node there are two types of threads: one Event Loop (aka the main loop, main thread, event thread, etc.), and a pool of k Workers in a Worker Pool (aka the threadpool).

If a thread is taking a long time to execute a callback (Event Loop) or a task (Worker), we call it "blocked". While a thread is blocked working on behalf of one client, it cannot handle requests from any other clients.

You can read more about it in [official nodejs guide](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)